# h5py: unable to open file in append mode on server

Tags: python-3.x, linux, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to open a hdf file using h5py in append mode. This file is located on a samba file server:

```
import h5py
path = "run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xyz.com,share=folder/file.h5"
h5f = h5py.File(path,mode="a")
```

this gives me the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 95] Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=xyz.com,share=folder/file.h5', errno = 95, error message = 'Operation not supported', flags = 1, o_flags = 2)
```

The code and path are correct, as I can open the dataset in read mode. The following code:

```
h5f = h5py.File(path,mode="r")
```

works. I also have the permission to write using instead `mode='w'`. Finally, the original code (in append mode) works if I copy file.h5 locally on my computer instead of accessing directly on the server.

I am using Manjaro Linux 22.0.4 with xfce desktop. All this makes me suspect that there is an incompatibility between Linux and the samba share, but I don't understand why it would only block me in append mode.

strace shows

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "Image 15_long.h5", O_RDWR) = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/aurelienb/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=21326, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffdf2e0aab0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 0)            = 4 sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f129480df50}, 8) = 0
exit_group(1)                   = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Try `export HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING=FALSE` on the terminal session where you run your code, then try again.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: Try to run this and post last couple dozen lines of output: `strace python -c "import h5py; h5py.File('filename.h5', 'a')"` replace the file name. Interesting output probably starts near the bottom with something like `openat(AT_FDCWD, "filename.h5", O_RDWR) = 3`

Comment: `openat(AT_FDCWD, "Image 15_long.h5", O_RDWR) = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)

[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/aurelienb/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=21326, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffdf2e0aab0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 0)            = 4
sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f129480df50}, 8) = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++`

Comment: Had to leave out some of it because of character limits, hope it helps anyway.

Comment: You can edit your question. Don't put that stuff in comments

Comment: Please verify that `touch "Image 15_long.h5"` also fails. At that point, it has nothing to do with h5py and is clearly a server/client issue. You probably have a better chance fixing it with the folks over at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). For example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/364203/cant-open-file-for-writing-with-cifs-mount)

Comment: `touch Image 15_long.h5 ` does not fail. "Change" time gets updated. Thanks!

Comment: Does `open(filename, 'r+')` in Python work?

Comment: No, 'r' and 'w' work but not 'r+'

Comment: Okay, so it's still something about the server/client. I suspect the gvfs stuff. If you can, replace it with a proper `mount -t cifs //xyz.com/folder` mount point. More info about the server (OS, version and stuff) would also help. But again, SO isn't the proper community for that kind of problem solving

Comment: [This](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/doc) documents that gvfs does not support all POSIX operations for all backends. Use a proper cifs mount and you should be fine.